# Python - Numpy Where Clause - The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to create a new column based on conditions from others columns. I have this dataframe:

```
number, flag_new, flag_math
1, TRUE, TRUE
2, FALSE, TRUE
3, TRUE, FALSE
```

If the flag_new is True and the flag_math is also TRUE I want to have 1 on the new column. If the flag_new is FALSE and the flag_math is TRUE I want to add 0 else -1.

The expected result is:

```
number, flag_new, flag_math, new_Column
    1, TRUE, TRUE, 1
    2, FALSE, TRUE, 0
    3, TRUE, FALSE, -1
```

For that I have this code:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['flag_new'] == 'TRUE' and df['flag_math'] == 'TRUE',1,
    np.where(df['flag_new'] == 'FALSE' and df['flag_math'] == 'TRUE',0, -1))
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `pandas` and `numpy` use the bitwise operators (&,|,~) to do boolean ops instead of `and` and `or` and `not`

Comment: alternatively you can use `np.where(df['flag_math'].eq('TRUE'), df['flag_new'].eq('TRUE').astype(int), -1)` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and and or are intended for scalar operations. Use numpy functions i.e. `np.logical_and()` and `np.logical_or()` for vector comparisons like your case. e.g.:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df['flag_new'] == 'TRUE', df['flag_math'] == 'TRUE'),1,
    np.where(np.logical_and(df['flag_new'] == 'FALSE', df['flag_math'] == 'TRUE'),0, -1))
```

Honestly though this logic in itself is a complex way to achieve this. You can simplify this in two steps and utilize these functions more efficiently.

A good way might be to parse columns as boolean values themselves (if they are not already) It will be helpful in any future analyses based on boolean values and `if(value)` is always more desirable than if `value=='TRUE'`.

```
def get_bool(key): #function derived from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64380962/7212929 
    return {'True':True, 'False':False}.get(key) if  key.title() in {'True':True, 'False':False}.keys() else bool(key)

df[['flag_new', 'flag_math']] = df[['flag_new', 'flag_math']].applymap(get_bool) # convert boolean representations into actual bools

df['new_col'] = df.flag_math -1 +np.logical_and(df.flag_new, df.flag_math)  # add new column with simplified new logic
```

result:

```
    number  flag_new    flag_math   new_col
0   1   True    True    1
1   2   False   True    0
2   3   True    False   -1
```